# For an Editable Interactive Grid, the Page attribute 'Reload on Submit' must be set to 'Only for Success'

Tags: oracle-apex-20.2, interactive-grid

I am new to Oracle APEX, after upgraded APEX Version to 20.2 my Tabular form getting Deprecated, so i have changed tabular form into Editable Interactive Grid, after changing that i am getting below error,

> For an Editable Interactive Grid, the Page attribute 'Reload on Submit' must be set to 'Only for Success'.

So while i am checking the issue i need to change the below setting on "Interactive Grid" region

**Set the Page attribute Advanced > Reload on Submit = “Only for Success”**

So I can't able to find **Reload on Submit** in the **Advanced**  Page property, screenshot

[image]

how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking in the Advanced section of the Interactive Grid. You will find the option in the page Rendering section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an ORDS bug... Keep the page property as "Only for Success".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).